# Update sister table with vertices as rows (when SHAPE is updated)

Tags: editing, oracle-spatial, oracle-dbms, vertices, sdo-geometry

I have an Oracle 18c table that has an SDO_GEOEMTRY column.

```
create table a_test_sdo_geom (id number, shape mdsys.sdo_geometry);

insert into a_test_sdo_geom (id, shape)
    values(1, sdo_util.from_wktgeometry (
               'MULTILINESTRING ((671834.096 4861699.7127, 671836.5099 4861701.9158), (671838.2206 4861700.7607, 671842.2311 4861703.3157))'));
insert into a_test_sdo_geom (id, shape)
    values(2, sdo_util.from_wktgeometry (
               'MULTILINESTRING ((671800.123 4861600.1234, 671800.1234 4861700.1234)))'));
commit;
```

And I have a sister table that stores the **vertices** from that table as rows:

```
create table a_test_vertices (id number, vertex_num number, x number, y number);

insert into a_test_vertices (
select
    a.id,
    v.id as vertex_num,
    v.x,
    v.y
from
    a_test_sdo_geom a
    ,table(sdo_util.getvertices(a.shape)) v
);
commit;

        ID VERTEX_NUM          X          Y
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 671834.096 4861699.71
         1          2 671836.510 4861701.92
         1          3 671838.221 4861700.76
         1          4 671842.231 4861703.32
         2          1 671800.123 4861600.12
         2          2 671800.123 4861700.12
```

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to automatically update the vertices table whenever the source table's SHAPE gets updated?

- When a source row is created
- When a source row is deleted
- When the source SHAPE column is updated (but not when any of the other columns get updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine provided the following:

---

Here is a **trigger** that will automatically update the vertices table whenever the source table's SHAPE gets updated:

- When a source row is created
- When a source row is deleted
- When the source SHAPE column is updated (but not when any of the other columns get updated)

---

```
create or replace trigger a_test_sdo_geom_trig
   before insert or update of shape or delete
   on a_test_sdo_geom
   for each row
begin
   case
      when inserting then
         insert into a_test_vertices (id, vertex_num, x, y)
         select :new.id, id, x, y
           from table(sdo_util.getvertices(:new.shape));
      when deleting then
         delete a_test_vertices
         where id = :old.id;
      when updating('shape') then
         merge into a_test_vertices a
            using (select id, x, y
                     from table(sdo_util.getvertices(:new.shape))) b
               on (a.vertex_num = b.id and a.id = :old.id)
            when matched then
               update
                  set x = b.x
                     ,y = b.y
            when not matched then
               insert(id, vertex_num, x, y)
               values(:old.id, b.id, b.x, b.y);
   end case;
end a_test_sdo_geom_trig;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into database triggers:

"PL/SQL Triggers: A trigger is like a stored procedure that Oracle Database invokes automatically whenever a specified event occurs."

[https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tdddg/using-triggers.html#GUID-3744214A-861D-4C59-AD2D-95840B5B0871](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-217E8B13-29EF-45F3-8D0F-2384F9F1D231)

Comment: Another option might be to use calculation attribute rules (if users use ArcGIS Pro exclusively, not ArcMap, and if ArcGIS Pro is a late enough version).